# Simple Modal add form dialog (telerik asp.net ajax)

Tags: asp.net, telerik, modalpopupextender

I have a RadTreeView in which there is a context menu to "Add" new items to the RadTreeView.  I have all the code to do this but I simply want a modal window/popup/dialog to launch in which I can have my simple add form.  What control (Telerik or not) would be best to handle this need?  I don't want to use RadWindow since that is like an iFrame and my add form needs to be within the page that contains the RadTreeView and using the AjaxPopupExtender seems to require me to jump through all sorts of css hoops in order to not have the window flicker on load, etc.  Any simple solutions out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you explain why the form "needs" to be within the page?  You can have the RadWindow do an postback after the update which causes the TreeView to refresh.

If you require an alternative solution, I might suggest either the RadTooltip (you can put a form in there) or the Obout Window (content stays within the control and not in an iFrame) ($99)

http://www.obout.com/window/example_Window_style_dogma.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Jquery has a really easy to use modal dialog

[Jquery UI docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form)